# Custom Bluetooth 5.0 audio transmitter analog LINE IN input attenuator from a 3W speaker amplifier

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I'm not a professional electronics engineer so I'm looking for some help in solving this problem:

I'm developing my own custom Bluetooth 5.0 audio transmitter module using a FSC-BT802 module from Feasycom, and I have a toy sound board with a 3W 5V mono speaker audio amplifier differential output.

This board also has an I2S or SPDIF audio output, but I would prefer to use it's speaker analog output instead (just for easier setup, I want to be able to swap a 3W 8 Ohm or 4 Ohm speaker with this Bluetooth transmitter module having a single 2-pin audio connector for both).

My BT802 module also has a differential analog LINE IN audio input (instead of the microphone) and I2S or SPDIF, but again, I prefer to use analog LINE IN. So I followed a recommended schematic by Feasycom in BT802 datasheet, made the PCB with audio level attenuator from 5V to 1V level using 10k resistors for Audio Negative and Audio Positive with a 5k resistor across them.

Sound gets lower volume but I always get a "white noise" on background in the remote speaker that receives this audio signal from my custom BT802 transmitter.

I also tried a recommended "single-ended" LINE IN input setup and it worked much better without a "white noise" on background, but I can't use it because I also need to connect a common GND wire between the toy sound board and the BT802 transmitter module in order to use RX/TX UART remote control interface (yes, I also need to use it in this setup). And since toy sound board has a differential speaker amplifier output, once I short the negative speaker audio output to GND, it loses audio, so I can't do that.

So the issue I'm struggling with is the "white noise" in the audio receiving remote speaker, which I think can be caused because of a too high LINE IN gain settings in the BT802 module itself.

So if lower the gain, noise may go away and will need to adjust audio input attenuator resistors for a good output volume. But why there is a noise only with "differential" input but no noise if I use "single-ended" LINE IN input schematic? End can you recommend a better audio LINE IN level attenuator schematic for my setup?
Thanks in advance!

Toy sound board speaker amplifier:
[PDF Datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX98357A-MAX98357B.pdf)

Single-ended input diagram:

[image]

Differential input diagram:

[image]

Comment: The toy sound board may be a Class D amp using PWM, so the speaker output has a high frequency component causing the noise. Since the sound board has spdif output and BT module has spdif input, why not use that? It will also eliminate distortion added by the 3W amp.

Comment: Speaker amplifier is MAX98357. I don't want to use SPDIF because it makes the whole setup more complicated, requires more connector contacts and it's not really straight forward to setup in the toy sound board... Do you know by any chance how I can filter that high frequency from the speaker amplifier?

Comment: You should probably use an LC filter. To help you select component values, you can search for "Class D audio output filter". Choose a cutoff frequency around 10 - 20 kHz.

Comment: Can I maybe just use some Op-Amp between differential speaker output and single-ended bluetooth module Line In input? To convert differential audio to single-ended. Because when I try single-ended, it works pretty well without noise.